# Groups of C# Attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

Is there any way to build a group of attributes?

Before:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1061")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1812")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1064")]
public abstract void Foo();
```

What I want:

```
[SpecialStuff]
public abstract void Foo();
```

Is this possible? Can I build an attribute that groups others?

Comment: I think it is a good idea... So that there is no need to add lots of [KnownType(typeof(.....))] in the wcf service interface. It just read  the resource file by the parameter ...like [ReadAllType(filepath)]

Comment: Maybe a good candidate for [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way attributes and their respective values are examined is usually through reflection - your special aggregate attribute `SpecialDispose` would not have any meaning since its unknown to a potential inspector so I do not think its possible to achieve what you want.